# IIS logs : sc bytes

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-6, httpmodule

What does sc-bytes represent ? every single discussion and blog about sc-bytes states that its represents bytes from server to client.

Want to know whether sc-bytes represents total response bytes,
for eg,. when we access any URL , does it include the bytes for css,js etc ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A single web page can be composed of tens or dozens of individual components. Only one of these is the document (html) requested. The browser will make additional requests for each js, css, image, etc file that is contained within or referenced from the html. And an extra request for favicon.ico for good measure.

Each one of these individual requests will appear in your IIS log as a separate row.

The sc-bytes column in each row is therefore a measurement of the bytes transferred from server to client for a single object request (e.g. a single image, a single css file).